# Explicit ODE IVPs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I've had a go at this question, just need pointing in the right direction.

> A linear scalar ODE of the form
>   $$ \frac{du}{dt}=:d_tu=:\dot{u}=5tu+\sin(t)   $$
>   $$ u(0)=1  $$
>   can be solved explicitly. Solve it. When does the scalar ODE have a unique solution? HINT: use the integrating factor
>   $$I(t):=\exp\left(-\int_0^t p(x)\ dx\right).$$

This is what I got:
$$ u(t)=\frac{\int \sin(t) \exp(-\int_0^t 5t\ dt)\ dt}{\exp(-\int_0^t 5t\ dt)}   $$
The ODE has a unique solution if it is continuous and if there exists a constant $C>0$.

Am I going along the right lines? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I wrote an answer, then realized I missed the factor. When put it there realized that it became the same. So, yes, your answer is correct. You also can simplify exponent as $\exp \left( \int_0^t 5t dt\right) = \exp \left( \frac {5t^2}2\right)$.

Comment: thank you very much for your time and help, it is very much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Integration factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor) is
$$
I(t) = \exp\left(-\int_0^x 5x dx \right) = \exp \left (-\frac {5t^2}2 \right)
$$
so ODE becomes
$$
\exp \left( -\frac {5t^2}2 \right) \frac {du}{dt} - 5t \exp \left(-\frac {5t^2}2 \right)u = \frac d{dt}\left[ \exp \left(-\frac{5t^2}2 \right) u\right] = \exp \left(-\frac {5t^2}2 \right)\sin t
$$
so after integration you'll get
$$
\exp \left( -\frac {5t^2}2\right)u = \int \sin t \exp \left( -\frac {5t^2}2\right)
$$
or as solution
$$
u = \exp \left(\frac {5t^2}2 \right)\int \frac {\sin t\ dt} {\exp \left(\frac { \displaystyle 5t^2}{\displaystyle 2}\right)}
$$